# Why i am getting empty array in Users.history:list API

Tags: php, gmail-api

I am trying to get history of changes done in gmail account using `Users:History` API with historyId. But somehow it is returns data after some seconds or minutes of changes done.

**Code**

```
function listHistory($service, $userId, $startHistoryId) {
  $opt_param = array('startHistoryId' => $startHistoryId);
  $pageToken = NULL;
  $histories = array();

  do {
    try {
      if ($pageToken) {
        $opt_param['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
      }
      $historyResponse = $service->users_history->listUsersHistory($userId, $opt_param);
      if ($historyResponse->getHistory()) {
        $histories = array_merge($histories, $historyResponse->getHistory());
        $pageToken = $historyResponse->getNextPageToken();
      }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
  } while ($pageToken);


  return $histories;
}
```

Ref: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will get an empty result for a given `startHistoryId` if there have been no changes to the user's email box since the particular point in time identified by that history ID.  That's the correct behavior.

And if you wait (second or minutes, as you suggest) and call again using the same starting history ID, and get results, those are the changes (new messages, etc.) that happened in the intervening time period.

And if you don't want to wait, and you have access to the Gmail account for testing, you can send a message to the account (or delete a message in the account) and you should see the corresponding changes when you call `Users.history.list` next.

For `historyId` values provided by push notifications, note the IDs provided are the **new** (current) history IDs.  See:  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push

> The HTTP POST body is JSON and the actual Gmail notification payload
>   is in the message.data field. That message.data field is a
>   base64url-encoded string that decodes to a JSON object containing the
>   email address and the new mailbox history ID for the user:
>
> {"emailAddress": "user@example.com", "historyId": "9876543210"} You
>   can then use history.list() **to get the change details for the user
>   since their last known historyId**, as per the sync guide.

(emphasis added).  To get the updates, you have to use the **previous** history ID.  Google has no way of knowing the latest history your application has tracked, so it's up to you to keep track of the history ID since you last did a history.list() operation.

Comment: I agree with you. But i have implemented Google push notification which will send notification when email address receives new email. In push notification i am getting `historyId` by which i can get `threadId` of received email using `Users.history.list` API. but when google sends push notification to my endpoint at that time API is returning empty response so i am not able to get details of new message in push notification

Comment: Answer updated for more information on using history IDs provided by push notifications.

Comment: Agree with @payne

Comment: Thank a lot! You save me:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to store `historyId` somewhere in Push notification and create a cron job that will fetch (using `Users.history.list` API) history of specific account with `historyId` you stored until it does not return response.